# Is there a section for software issues?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm wondering if there is a section for software issues where others will help you set up software correctly?

For instance, I recently installed a piece of software called rebox.NET (it is freeware that allows me to remux the audio of a mkv file to mp4). However, it is having issues with the audio syncing up with the video. I had read on a forum that this could be caused due to DirectShow filters not working properly with Windows 7.

The above is a pretty good example when someone isn't sure how to fix said issue and there isn't a whole lot of documentation on the software that a section like this would benefit quite a few.

So I'm wondering, is there already a section of Stack Exchange for this and I simply missed it? Or am I stuck having to register to various forums hoping people can help me out?

Comment: That sounds more like something for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)? Check though. I don't participate there.

Comment: @bart Thank you I will have a peak and report back if it is indeed the correct place. **Edit** After a very quick peak, it looks like it may indeed be the place to ask this question. Thank you!